# Как найти определённый элемент и изменить его? Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как с помощью jquery найти нужный мне элемент в такой конструкции?
У меня получается только цеплять весь класс, но мне нужен определённый элемент. Выглядит это примерно так:

```html
<div class="_SomeClass">

<span class="_AnotherClass"></span>

<a class="_SupaClass noHover" href="google.com">

<span class="ClassWith Space">

<table class="visible-one visible-two">

<tbody>

<tr>
<td class="_RightClass">Check</td><td>Text</td>   //check
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="_RightClass">Avoid</td><td>Text</td>   //skip
</tr>

</tbody></table></span></a></div>
```

Пытался искать по тексту, но текст там тоже одинаковый. :(

```
$('td:contains("Text")').text("Gotcha");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('td._RightClass:contains("Avoid")').next("td").text("Gotcha");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="visible-one visible-two">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="_RightClass">Check</td>
      <td>Text</td> //check
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="_RightClass">Avoid</td>
      <td>Text</td> //skip
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Но как в таком случае искать классы в которых есть пробел? Такой как `<table class="visible-one visible-two">`

Comment: @peltesi Обычным css-селектором - `$('table.visible-one.visible-two')`